# Diophantine equation (three variables)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

> Show that the equation $$x^3+2y^2+4z=n$$ has an integer solution $(x,y,z)$ for all integers $n$.

This seems to be an Diophantine equation with three variables. How can I restrict $n$ in order to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $n=4k$, then $(x,y,z)=(0,0,k)$ can work.

If $n=4k+1$, then $(x,y,z)=(1,0,k)$.

If $n=4k+2$, then $(x,y,z)=(0,1,k)$.

If $n=4k+3$, then $(x,y,z)=(1,1,k)$.

Since any integer $n$ will be in one of the above forms ($4k+r$), hence the equation has integer solutions for all $n$.

Comment: How did you get $n=4k$ etc ?

Comment: @Nate when you divide any integer by $4$, the set of possible remainders will be $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: But I meant from the given equation $x^3+2y^2+4z=n$ how did you came up with $4k$? For example why wouldn't $2k$ work?

Comment: @Nate I had to partition integers into (disjoint) sets so $4$ works better in this case than $2$. Because with $n=2k$ it will be a bit more involved to cover all cases. For example we can say with $n=2k^2$, we can have $(0,k,0)$ as a solution. But then we are not covering those even numbers which are of the form $2s$, where $s$ is NOT a square. So we will have to construct a solution for those left out cases separately.